# Does NSFileManager copy metadata like modification dates along with files?

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager

The documentation for [`[NSFileManager copyPath:toPath:handler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1557010-copypath?language=objc), a deprecated method, says:

> File or directory attributes—that is, metadata such as owner and group numbers, file permissions, and modification date—are also copied.

This is not stated in the docs for [`copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412957-copyitematurl?language=objc) or [`copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407903-copyitematpath?language=objc). But is it also true of those methods? If I have file `foo/bar.txt` with a modified date of one hour ago, and I copy it to `baz/bar.txt`, and then I get the modification date of `baz/bar.txt` using [`attributesOfItemAtPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410452-attributesofitematpath?language=objc), will it be now or one hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with this code:

```
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
    NSString *firstPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test1.dat"];
    NSData *data = [@"Foobar Test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:firstPath atomically:YES];

    NSDate *firstModDate = (NSDate *)[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:firstPath error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *secondPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test2.dat"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:firstPath toPath:secondPath error:nil];
        NSDate *secondDate = (NSDate *)[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:secondPath error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

        NSLog(@"Original date: %.2f", firstModDate.timeIntervalSince1970);
        NSLog(@"New date: %.2f", secondDate.timeIntervalSince1970);
    });
```

And it logs the same date twice. So it does indeed preserve modification date metadata. Tested with iOS 13.3.